# Assign javascript function output to liquid variable

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to validate an image URL if it exists in javascript. So I add this code in javascript which accepts a URL and returns the http status code.

```
function imageExists(image_url){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}
```

And in the liquid template, I want to check the image URL if it exists before displaying kinda like this

```
<div class="variant-cat-attributes">
  {% assign tags = product.metafields.product_meta.tag | split: "," %}
  {% for tag in tags %}
      <div class="item">
      {% capture tag_slug %}{{ tag | replace: " ", "_"}}{% endcapture %}
      {% assign img_png = 'tag' | append: '-' | append: tag_slug | append: '.png'%}
      {% capture png_exists %}<script>imageExists({{ img_png }})</script>{% endcapture %}
      {% if png_exists%}
        <img src="{{ img_png | file_img_url: '32x32' }}" />
      {% else %}
        {% assign img_jpg = 'tag' | append: '-' | append: tag_slug | append: '.jpg'%}
        {% capture jpg_exists %}<script>imageExists({{ img_jpg }})</script>{% endcapture %}
        {% if jpg_exists%}
          <img src="{{ img_png | file_img_url: '32x32' }}" />
        {% else %}
          {% assign img_default = 'tag' | append: '-' | append: 'default' | append: '.png'%}
          <img src="{{ img_default | file_img_url: '32x32' }}" />
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      <p class="item-name">{{ tag | capitalize }}</p></div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I'm just starting to understand liquid so I don't know if its correct this way. But what happens with this code is the script tag is taken up as a string and the code in it is not run

> png_exists = imageExists({{ img_png }})

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mix matching JS with Liquid, which is OK if you only pass liquid content.

At the moment liquid see your code like so:

```
{% capture png_exists %}<script>imageExists({{ img_png }})</script>{% endcapture %}

png_exists => <script>imageExists(http://asset_img_url.jpg)</script>
```

You can't execute Javascript code and expect liquid to know about it, Javascript is executed AFTER liquid, so liquid finish it's logic and Javascript will run it's code afterwards.

So you you can't use javascript functionality in liquid.

Comment: I know that. I want to know how can I fix it? How can I edit the code so that js isn't inside liquid?

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar you can use an image tag with an error state `<img src="{{img_png | asset_url }}" onError="style.display = 'none';">` no easy way to check if an asset exist or not with liquid.

Comment: That does not work. I need to display a default image if the image does not exist and also to check for jpg image before that.

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar well you can do that with Javascript logic based on the error state above. You will just have two images and show either of them depending if the error state fires or not, there are other JS approaches as well. I think it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Well thats what I need. An approach on how to fix it. Can you post one as an answer?